# Request focus on edittext is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 4 edittexts that act as a "enter your pin" field with each edittext set to only be able to take a single number before requesting focus to the next edittext. If I enter a number for the 1st pin, it then request focus to the 2nd, and then 3rd, etc.

What I am trying to do now is, if the user clicks on the 2nd edittext or 3rd and the 1st field has not been entered, it should go back and focus on the 1st field.

[The edittext fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXBWo.png)

I tried to do this using an onTouchListener and what I noticed is that after clicking on the 2nd edittext first instead of clicking on the left/1st edittext, I can see the focus going back to the first edittext but then immediately go back to the 2nd edittext almost a split second and ultimately still remain focus on the 2nd edittext.

I also tested using onClickListener. It does work but it takes two clicks. So I'll click on the 2nd edittext, nothing happens, and then I click it again which then moves the focus back to the 1st edittext but I need it to happen on the first click.

Here is part of the code

```
pin1EditTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(pin1EditTxt.getText().toString().length()==1)     //size as per your requirement
                {
                    pin2EditTxt.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });

//        pin2EditTxt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//                if(pin1EditTxt.length() == 0){
//                    pin2EditTxt.clearFocus();
//                    pin1EditTxt.requestFocus();
//                }
//                return false;
//            }
//        });

        pin2EditTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(pin1EditTxt.length() == 0){
                    pin1EditTxt.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        
        pin2EditTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(pin2EditTxt.getText().toString().length()==1)     //size as per your requirement
                {
                    pin3EditTxt.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });

        pin3EditTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(pin3EditTxt.getText().toString().length()==1)     //size as per your requirement
                {
                    pin4EditTxt.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });

        pin4EditTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //Hide keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
                editTxtWrapper.requestFocus();
            }
        });
```

Comment: What you are trying to so can be a pain if you use `TextWatcher` for it with 4 `Edittext`. I have been there . Have a look at [This view](https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText) it fulfill the purpose. You can look at source code and learn.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be using pin1EditTxt.getText().toString().length()==0 instead of pin1EditTxt.length()==0 inside onclick.